# Problem with same legend for two layers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

In Leaflet, I have two layers (treated as overlays) and a single legend that I want to appear when any of them is checked in the Layer Control panel. If they are both checked, I don't want it to appear twice.
This is the code:

```js
map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer) {
  if (eventLayer.name === 'Drumuri județene' || eventLayer.name === 'Drumuri comunale') {
    legend1.addTo(map);
  } else {
    if (others < 1) {
      legend1.addTo(map);
    }
    others++;
  }
});

map.on('overlayremove', function(eventLayer) {
  if (eventLayer.name === 'Drumuri județene' || eventLayer.name === 'Drumuri comunale') {
    this.removeControl(legend1);
  } else {
    if (others < 1) {
      this.removeControl(legend1);
    }
  }
});
```

The problem with it is that it works only if they are checked and unchecked separately. If they are both visible, two identical legends appear and If I uncheck them one after the other, one of the legends fails to dissapear. I can tell there is something wrong, but I don't have the programming knowledge to solve it. Can someone offer a solution?

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: @underdark I changed it. Thank you for the indication.

Comment: Could you describe your expected behavior a little more? Specifically, are there other layers (besides these two) in the Layer Control? And is this legend the only one that you will be adding to the map, or are there legends for other layers as well? The code you've posted seems to be based on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/7LskL5e1/), which is designed to handle different legends for different sets of layers, even though here you are only adding and removing `legend1`.

Comment: @nathansnider There are five more layers, but I don't want any legend to show up for any of them. `legend1`is the only one that I would like to add. It must show up when any of the two layers is active, must dissapear when both of them are hidden and must appear only once if they are both visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't explained what the variable 'others' is storing, but you need more information that just what has changed.

You could look through the layers that have been added, but since you're catching all layers added or removed, I think you can simply store a variable and use this to handle your logic.

Try this (or something close:

```js
var numEnabledLayers = 0;
var legendAdded = false;
map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer) {
  if (eventLayer.name === 'Drumuri județene' || eventLayer.name === 'Drumuri comunale') {
    numEnabledLayers ++;
    if(numEnabledLayers === 2 and !legendAdded) {
      legend1.addTo(map);
      legendAdded = true;
    }
  } 
});

map.on('overlayremove', function(eventLayer) {
  if (eventLayer.name === 'Drumuri județene' || eventLayer.name === 'Drumuri comunale') {
    numEnabledLayers --;
    if(legendAdded) {
      this.removeControl(legend1);
      legendAdded = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I only had to change a few things, but it works very good.

Comment: Maybe let me know what you changed it it's important?